# How to filter a dataframe by user inputs in Django filter?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter, django-pandas

I want to filter a dataframe that is pivoted from a model.

Model.py is:

```
class MTD(models.Model):
    RGN = models.CharField(max_length = 60, db_column = 'RGN')
    Channel = models.CharField(max_length = 60, db_column = 'Channel')
    Vertical = models.CharField(max_length = 60, db_column = 'Vertical')
    Brand = models.CharField(max_length = 60, db_column = 'Brand')
    Sales_Value = models.CharField(max_length = 60, db_column = 'Sales Value')
    Month = models.CharField(max_length = 60, db_column = 'Month')

    City = models.CharField(max_length = 60, db_column = 'City')

    objects = models.Manager()
    pdobjects = DataFrameManager()


    def __str__(self):
            field_values = []
            for field in self._meta.get_fields():
                field_values.append(str(getattr(self, field.name, '')))
            return ' '.join(field_values)
```

I am filtering only three columns from my model ('VERTICAL', 'CHANNEL', 'SALES VALUE') and I am converting this into a dataframe. From the derived dataframe I am not able to filter the data as requested by the user. I am posting the code which I have tried so far.

Table.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <h1>Pandas dataframe from MyModel</h1>
    <form method="GET">
      {{ filter.form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    {{ filter|safe }}
    {{ Table|safe }}

  </body>
</html>
```

Filter.py

```
from dash.models import MTD
import django_filters

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = MTD
        fields = ['Vertical', 'Channel', ]
```

Views.py

```
from dash.filter import UserFilter


def salebycustomer(request):
    sbc = MTD.pdobjects.values('Vertical', 'Channel','Sales_Value')
    user_filter = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=sbc)
    sbc_df = sbc.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=True)#Trying to use filtered model for dataframe
    sbc_df['Sales_Value']=sbc_df['Sales_Value'].astype(float)

    sbc_df1 = pandas.pivot_table(sbc_df,values='Sales_Value', index='Vertical', columns='Channel',aggfunc='sum').rename_axis(None,axis=1).replace(numpy.nan,0)
    sbc_df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

    # sbc_df1.columns = [''.join(col).strip() for col in sbc_df1.columns.values]

    # sbc_df1=sbc_df1.T.to_dict().values()
    template = 'table.html'


    sbc_df2 = sbc_df1.to_html()

    context= {'filter': user_filter,'Table':sbc_df2}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Plz help me to resolve this.
[Kindly refer this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZlLH.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware, that while you create your `user_filter` you don't use it to create your output in the template or to actually filter something in your view. Pay special attention to [this section](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#the-template) of the django_filter documentation. The filter is used to generate the output as well (not just the form).

Comment: Thank u @Bloodmallet -Is there any other technique to implement the user-filtered model to a dataframe

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with any of your tools yet. I only stumbled uppon this, because creating a filter without using it looked wrong to me. And a quick look at the documentation of django_filter proved this suspicion correct. Even though it might sound annoying, your use-case sounds pretty standard, so reading the docs of the tools you use should cover that pretty quickly.